# Loading local GeoJSON file in OpenLayers without Geoserver

Tags: openlayers, geojson

I have a GeoJSON file saved locally and it is also present on GeoServer. 
I can successfully load it as a vector layer in my OpenLayers map when pointing to its GeoServer URL.

Is it possible to load the locally saved file without the use of GeoServer?

This is the error I get when I try to load it locally:

```
Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes:
http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https*"
```

Comment: How are you trying to load it, when using it locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick overview, you can find countless answers for your 'problem' on the web:

Browsers (or more specific: clientside *Javascript*) in general are not permittet access to the local file system programmatically (without specific user interaction) ([Same-Origin-Policy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)).

Your options here include

- using [HTML5 File API](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) to let the user select a local file
- a local http server instance (mainly for developement purposes), for example via [Python 3.x](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html)
- serving it via the public file system on your webserver (e.g. not locally)

There are tons of workarounds, but they are to be used with caution; the Same-Origin-Policy is a security implementation and its implications have good reasons to be followed!